# bootstrap-datepicker formatting date outpt

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this code to get the date from the bootstrap-datepicker. I found several question swith the same issue and none of them seem to work for me. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
<div id="dateCal"></div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$input = $("#dateCal");

$input.datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e){
        console.log(e.date);
    });
```

and mu console output looks like this:

```
Sat Jun 21 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

What am I doing wrong? I need e.date to come out as the format option is set.

Comment: And `$(e).val()`? If `e.date` is a Date object, it will be converted using the browser local settings when displaying...

Comment: { console.log( $(e).val() ); } - throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined ... so returns udnefined

Answer (score 1):

When processing events in javascript (and jQuery or bootstrap), the "e" passed to the function is [the event object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).  Reading `e.date` could refer to the datetime of the event.  You want to be reading `this.value`, where *this* refers to the HTML element associated with the event, or in this case, your date field.

Do instead:

```
  console.log(this.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When I do that I get the date value but the formatting is still incorrect. I get 06/26/2014 while I need 06-26-2014.

Comment: My guess is, you need to use dateFormat instead of format.  Here's an example of it working in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a63P6/1/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is not the same datepicker however and I resolved the issue. I will post later what I did.

Comment: Good Job!  I use it in `.on('changeDate', function(e){ })` is ok